# Append excel spreadsheets using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have following data sets in in a folder:

a) 10 excel spreadsheets (with different names)

b) each spreadsheet has 7 tabs. Out of the 7 tabs per spreadsheet, 2 are having exactly same names where as the rest 5 have different sheet names.

c) I need to concatenate the five excel sheets from 10 different spreadsheets.

d) In all 10*5 sheets need to be concatenated.

How do I go about doing this so that I can concatenate all 50 spreadsheets and final out put is one 'Master' spreadsheet with all 50 spreadsheets appended (without concatenating the two sheets with exactly same names in each excel file)?

I am using the following code to concatenate sheets using jupyter notebook, but it is not helping out:

```
​import pandas as pd

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('A://Data/File.xlsx')
data_sheets = []
for sheet in xlsx.sheet_names:
    data_sheets.append(xlsx.parse(sheet))
data = pd.concat(data_sheets)
print(data)
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do all the sheets have the same data structure?

Comment: @dubbbdan Yes, all the five (which have different names) have exactly same data structure the other two (which have same names in all excel files) have entirely different data structures. I am not concerned about the two which have same names. I need data from the 5.

Comment: Are they always in the same order?  How do you know which sheet (with the duplicate name) is the one you want?

Comment: @ dubbbdan, example: Say: First spreadsheet has following sheet names: ['A','B',1,2,3,4,5] and second spreadsheet has following sheet names: ['A','B',9,10,11,12,13]. Common are sheets 'A' and 'B' (i do not need these) whereas rest all needs to be appended below each other.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to read all the worksheets in 10 workbooks and append each data frame to the list `data_sheets`. One approach would be to allocate a list `names_to_find` and append each sheet name while you iterate.

```
names_to_find =[]
data_sheets = []
for excelfile in excelfile_list:
   xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(excelfile)

   for sheet in xlsx.sheet_names:
      data_sheets.append(xlsx.parse(sheet))
      names_to_find.append(sheet)
```

After all the data has been read, you can use `names_to_find` and `np.unique` to find the unique sheet names and their frequency.

```
#find unique elements and return counts
unique, counts = np.unique(names_to_find,return_counts=True)

#find unique sheet names with a frequency of one
unique_set = unique[counts==1]
```

You can then use `np.argwhere` to find the indices where `unique_set` exists in `names_to_find`

```
#find the indices where the unique sheet names exist 
idx_to_select = np.argwhere(np.isin(names_to_find, unique_set)).flatten()
```

Finally, a bit of list comprehension and you can subset `data_sheets` to contain the data of interest:

```
#use list comprehension to subset data_sheets 
data_sheets = [data_sheets[i] for i in idx_to_select]
data = pd.concat(data_sheets)
```

All together:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
names_to_find =[]
data_sheets = []
for excelfile in excelfile_list:    
   xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(excelfile)

   for sheet in xlsx.sheet_names:        
      data_sheets.append(xlsx.parse(sheet))
      names_to_find.append(sheet)

#find unique elements and return counts
unique, counts = np.unique(names_to_find,return_counts=True)

#find unique sheet names with frequency of 1
unique_set = unique[counts==1]

#find the indices where the unique sheet names exist 
idx_to_select = np.argwhere(np.isin(names_to_find, unique_set)).flatten()

#use list comprehension to subset data_sheets subset data_sheets
data_sheets = [data_sheets[i] for i in idx_to_select]

#concat the data
data = pd.concat(data_sheets)
```

Comment: should I put names of data_sheets in the empty lists? it is giving error: "No objects to concatenate". Where should I type name of excel sheets?

Comment: where should I add names of: a) 5 sheets and b) 10 workbooks? Also, do I need to define excelfile_list?

Comment: excelfile_list should be a list of all the excel files you want to process.  glob.glob is your friend.

Comment: and where do I add list of a) data_sheets to be appended and b) data_sheets to be not considered for appending?

Comment: This routine will decide which worksheets to append for you.  All you need to is define excelfiles_list at the top of the code.  Something like ‘excelfile_list= glob.glob(‘some_directory//*.xlsx’)’. Then run the code.  If you want to see which sheets were appended, have a look at ‘unique_set’. It should have a length of 50.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190404/discussion-between-excelislife-and-dubbbdan).

Comment: I have added code to the 'continue this discussion in chat' section